# Setting up SCSS color variables won't work

Tags: css, npm, sass, visual-studio-code

I'd like to define my own color variables in my SCSS, but how?

I checked [this website](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/tutorials/scss-color-variables/) and did everything that is described there.. but it doesn't work.

I have installed a preprocessor already!

Furthermore I tried to create a color-map and access the color with map-get.. doesn't work either.

colors.scss file

```
$yellow_100: #FFC819;
```

style.scss file with a colors.scss import

```
h1 {
    color: $yellow_100;
}
```

I also tried this:

colors.scss file

```
$colors: (
    color: #FFBB00
);
```

style.scss file

```
h1 {
    color: map-get($colors, color);
}
```

Neither of them works.

Comment: You probably need to check you preprocessor again, the codes your provided work well.

Comment: Your code all looks fine to me. Please explain what "doesn't work" means. Do you have an error when compiling, does the CSS not update, etc.

Comment: Your code looks fine, can you share complete code. Thanks

Comment: Nor error message.. it compiled successfully.
Are there multiple preprocessors?

Comment: Are you actually compiling your SASS file into CSS? and can you post the compiled CSS file?

Comment: HTML
`<h1>Test</h1>`
colors.scss
`$yellow_100: #FFC819;`
style.scss
`h1 {
    color:$yellow_100;
}`

Comment: Do you not have a `style.css` file? And maybe a `style.min.css` as well?

Comment: No, I only have .scss files. I will now try with .css

Comment: @dominic That's the reason it isn't working then; you need to compile all your `scss` files into one big `css` file - this is what you then link in your HTML. There are many ways that you can compile your SASS - but since you're using VS Code, you can just get a free extension that'll do it for you.

Answer (score 5):

SASS compiler preserves `$` in output CSS and doesn't recognize `$yellow_100` as a SASS variable. Use [Interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) to access variable's value instead of its name—just put it between `#{` and `}`.

So your code should look like:

```
$yellow_100: #FFC819;

h1 {
  color: #{$yellow_100};
}
```

---

Interpolation isn't used in old code examples. That's because SASS developers changed the syntax approximately in July, 2017, making interpolation mandatory for SASS variables. [Here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars) is more details on this.

Comment: Do you think you could include a quote from one of those links to make your answer more complete?

Comment: @RamenChef, sure, added some details

Answer (score 1):

1. Install sass with `npm -g install sass`
2. Create these two source files:

```
// _colors.scss
$yellow_100: #FFC819;

// style.scss
@import './colors';

h1 {
    color: $yellow_100;
}
```

3. Execute `sass ./style.scss ./output.css` to compile your code
4. Add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href"[path to output.css]" />` to your HTML

Comment: Well, I am just playing a little bit around with SASS and tried to define my own color variables.

I have an <h1> tag in my HTML and wanted to change the color.

it compiled successfully but the color doesn't change.

Any idea which preprocessor I need to install? Are there multiple one?

I did this: npm -g install preprocessor

Comment: Oh and yes.. I did import my colors.scss file

Comment: @dominic Does the output of the compiled css look correct?

Comment: @dominic I'd use `npm -g install sass` https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass

Comment: Well, it looks fine to me. It works when I use color codes like `h1 { color: #FFC819; }`

Comment: I did Jamie! I also used `npm -g install sass` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @dominic Could you post the contents of the output file?

Comment: @dominic See updated answer, just tested this locally with the following output:

output.css: 

h1 {
  color: #FFC819;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=output.css.map */

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using single colons to prefix your root header tag in your `.scss` files.
i.e `:root{}` and not `::root{}`