# How to extend a variable's map in SCSS?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, bulma, buefy

I am using a package called Buefy which is a Vue.js wrapper for the Bulma CSS framework library. Buefy puts an attribute/property on its template components called `type` (*e.g.*, `type="is-warning"`). As per the [Buefy documentation](https://buefy.org/documentation/button/#api-view), the term "is-warning" is pre-defined according to the `$colors` variable set within SCSS:

[image: https://buefy.org/documentation/button/#api-view]

So I followed [these instructions from Buefy](https://buefy.org/documentation/customization/) to be able to customize the the `$colors` map, but what I would like to do, however, is keep the initial SCSS defined in those instructions within a single `base.scss` file, and then extend with my own customized SCSS file.

I have included the `base.scss` file in my Vue project with the following snippet in the `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: `
          @import "@/assets/scss/base.scss";
        `
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So my question is, how can I extend the `$colors` map in the `base.scss` with my own names and values?

This is a snippet from `base.scss`, where the `$colors` map is defined:

````
```css
$colors: (
  "white": ($white, $black),
  "black": ($black, $white),
  "light": ($light, $light-invert),
  "dark": ($dark, $dark-invert),
  "primary": ($primary, $primary-invert),
  "info": ($info, $info-invert),
  "success": ($success, $success-invert),
  "warning": ($warning, $warning-invert),
  "danger": ($danger, $danger-invert),
  "twitter": ($twitter, $twitter-invert)
);
```
````

So, again, my question is **how can I extend the `$colors` map in a different file outside of `base.scss` (perhaps in `App.vue`) to leave the original untouched?** I didn't see any solution shown in the [scss docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map).

Comment: Hope this is usefull for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/55470403/1912544

Comment: @kris I don't see how that explains how to extend the `$colors` map or what an alternative pattern would be to allow for what I described. Vue.js's `.vue` files have a `<styles lang="scss">` portion and the scss code is automatically compiled.

Answer (score 2):

Your custom color values would go in a variable (later merged into `$colors`) called `$custom-colors`, and it's actually described in the docs on ["derived variables"](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/variables/#derived-variables).

And to customize it:

```
// Import Bulma's core
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all";

// Set your colors
$custom-colors: (
  "facebook": ($blue, $white),
  "linkedin": ($dark-blue, $white)
  // etc.
);

// Setup $colors to use as bulma classes (e.g. 'is-twitter')
$colors: (
  "white": ($white, $black),
  "black": ($black, $white),
  "light": ($light, $light-invert),
  "dark": ($dark, $dark-invert),
  "primary": ($primary, $primary-invert),
  "info": ($info, $info-invert),
  "success": ($success, $success-invert),
  "warning": ($warning, $warning-invert),
  "danger": ($danger, $danger-invert),
  "twitter": ($twitter, $twitter-invert)
);

// Import Bulma and Buefy styles
@import "~bulma";
@import "~buefy/src/scss/buefy";
```

It's internally using a custom function called [`mergeColorMaps`](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/0dc44161bcef0aa5eed38680af7b04cea416b6f2/sass/utilities/functions.sass#L1).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This would, however, require that I define my `$custom-colors` within `base.scss` as well. Is there a way I can leave `base.scss` untouched? Ideally, I would like to define `$custom-colors` within `App.vue` (if you're familiar with Vue.js). But if that is not possible, then I suppose I would need an import into `base.css` for a `myStyles.scss` where I create my custom definitions?

Comment: @Raj You don't necessarily need to redefine the variable there. If you follow the order of `import`s shown above (as well as in the docs), you should be able to define this `$custom-colors` elsewhere and import it just before the Bulma styles.

Comment: So essentially, yes to importing `myStyles.scss` right **before** `base.scss` to `App.vue` or your entry file.

Comment: I just tried setting `$custom-colors` but it never works unless I name the variable `$colors` instead. Is it because Buefy uses version 0.7.5 of Bulma?

Comment: @Raj Weird. It's clearly defined there in [`derived-variables.sass`](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/0dc44161bcef0aa5eed38680af7b04cea416b6f2/sass/utilities/derived-variables.sass#L100). Are you able to create a reproducible example (jsfiddle or codesandbox) showing how it's not rendering the right results for you?

Comment: "Transpiling modules" takes some time, but you can see that `$custom-colors` is ignored with the definition of `'foo'`, though when it's in `$colors` it is obeyed: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-forest-3gm4n?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: I tried your codesandbox and it did seem like it's taking ages to compile. Not sure why, not a Buefy user myself. However, according to [the Bulma docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-sass-cli/#6-add-your-own-bulma-styles), your custom styles are supposed to be added *before* the `utilities`, which is interestingly contrary to the Buefy docs on Bulma (customization) where it says to put these custom styles *after* the `utilities`.

Comment: As for the prolonged compilation time, maybe try the *a-la-carte* way (to include **only** styles/components needed). https://buefy.org/documentation/start

Comment: Adding the `$custom-colors` definition before the `@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all"` in my `base.scss` file only works if I don't also have a `$colors` variable definition at all (even if the `map` has completely different keys). So in conclusion, I cannot define my `$custom-colors` within `App.vue`? I have to define it within `base.scss` or perhaps some other file and `@import` it into `base.scss`. And furthermore, I should not have any `$colors` definition because it will somehow break the ability to have a `$custom-colors` definition?

Comment: Well, you are talking about "extending" color maps, and yet you are actually "replacing" its *base* values by (re)defining `$colors`. So leave out this `$colors` value-reassignment in your `base.scss` and instead put any custom colors in `$custom-colors` and that should do the trick: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-snowflake-e7i5e?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: In my actual project, when I follow the pattern in your sandbox ( https://paste.ee/p/HUcNo ) I get this error https://paste.ee/p/BcLKq ...since this comment thread is getting quite long, I created a new SO question regarding the error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62145556/sasserror-argument-color-of-darkencolor-amount-must-be-a-color