# SassError: argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, bulma, buefy

I am attempting to add a custom color map in Bulma, with the following SCSS code:

```js
// Set your colors
$primary: #5B43CC;
$primary-invert: findColorInvert($primary);
$twitter: #4099FF;
$twitter-invert: findColorInvert($twitter);
$facebook: #4267B2;
$facebook-invert: findColorInvert($facebook);

$custom-colors: (
  "foo": (black, grey),
);

// Import Bulma's core
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all";

// Links
$link: $primary;
$link-invert: $primary-invert;
$link-focus-border: $primary;

// Import Bulma and Buefy styles 
// this has been moved to App.vue because it must be at the end
@import "~bulma";
@import "~buefy/src/scss/buefy";
```

But I get the following error:

```js
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 6 errors                                                                                                           1:26:26 AM

 error  in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color
        on line 150 of node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/button.sass, in function `darken`
        from line 150 of node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/button.sass
        from line 4 of node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/_all.sass
        from line 5 of node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass
        from line 40 of src/assets/scss/main.scss
        from line 2 of /c/Users/Raj/Projects/testsite/src/App.vue
>>           background-color: darken($color-invert, 5%); }

   ----------------------------^


 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss& 4:14-416 14:3-18:5 15:22-424
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

However, if I comment out `// $primary-invert: findColorInvert($primary);` then the error goes away. Also, if the snippet under `// set your colors` is moved after `@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all"`, then the error also goes away.

What am I doing wrong here?

*Note, this is a follow-up to [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62112173/how-to-extend-a-variables-map-in-scss)*

Comment: Can you confirm if `$color-invert` is indeed a valid color (hex) value?

Comment: @YomS. I have no SCSS code that states `$color-invert`. My only SCSS code is what I posted in the first code block. `darken($color-invert)` must be used internally by Bulma

Comment: Aren't you doing `background-color: darken($color-invert, 5%);` somewhere in the `App.vue`?  Nevermind that though, since you have confirmed not declaring anything in that regard.

Comment: @YomS. No, the only SCSS is in App.vue, which contains what I've shown in the first code block above. (To simplify things, I got rid of `base.scss` that was discussed in the previous post that I linked)

Comment: Those color inversions are using a function called [`findColorInvert`](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/0dc44161bcef0aa5eed38680af7b04cea416b6f2/sass/utilities/functions.sass#L79) which resides within `utilities/functions.sass`, so maybe it's the ordering again. Try moving those lines (and only them, not the `$custom-colors`) *after* the `utilities/_all`.

Comment: @YomS. Yes that would work, but then my `$custom-color` can't make use of those variables. Additionally, that problem does not occur in your codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-snowflake-e7i5e?file=/src/App.vue Any idea why? I am also confused why only `findColorInvert($primary)` causes this issue and not the other two inverts.

Comment: Then you might have to try one more thing: reorder your custom variables *very carefully* in between the [`utilities` imports](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/sass/utilities/_all.sass), in place of the bulk import (`_all.sass`). When it comes to Sass compilation, it's all about ordering.

Comment: I know this is too much to ask, but it'd be great if you could put the copy (based on the original) of the *relevant* source code on GitHub repo, for in-depth investigation. Otherwise, it's gonna be difficult to see what's really happening from here.

Comment: @YomS. You were correct, I split `_all.sass` up into its component parts and placed the variables after the `functions.sass` import and it no longer gives an error with this order: https://paste.ee/p/9QAoO I still don't understand why your codesandbox link didn't cause that error though even though it was using bulma's `_all.sass` after the variable definitions?

Comment: It not happening on the codesandbox is indeed weird, not quite sure myself lol. It could just be warnings that get ignored by the compiler, maybe [`@debug`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/debug) it for detailed logs.

Comment: @YomS. You can add your splitting up `_all.sass` solution so I can upvote and select it. In terms of the Github repo, which source code are you suggesting to put up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as I mentioned in the comments, when it comes to Sass compilation it's all about ordering (of `import`s and/or variable declarations). Now, since those color inversions are using a Bulma utility called [`findColorInvert`](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/0dc44161bcef0aa5eed38680af7b04cea416b6f2/sass/utilities/functions.sass#L79), which resides within `utilities/functions.sass`, we can't probably import the `utilities` with the [original order](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/sass/utilities/_all.sass) here.

We could split them and insert our customs in between the `functions` and `derived-variables`:

```
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables";
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/functions";

// Set your colors
$primary: #5B43CC;
$primary-invert: findColorInvert($primary);
$twitter: #4099FF;
$twitter-invert: findColorInvert($twitter);
$facebook: #4267B2;
$facebook-invert: findColorInvert($facebook);

// Links
$link: $primary;
$link-invert: $primary-invert;
$link-focus-border: $primary;

$custom-colors: (
  "foo": (black, grey),
);

@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/derived-variables";
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/animations";
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/mixins";
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/controls";
```

Comment: why does defining `$colors` make `$custom-colors` no longer get obeyed? I thought `mergeColorMaps()` would allow both to work, and in fact, the 2nd argument (in this case `$custom-colors`) would override any overlapping keys that are in both the maps. https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/0dc44161bcef0aa5eed38680af7b04cea416b6f2/sass/utilities/functions.sass#L1

Comment: I believe it's because it is *not* merging `$colors` with *`$custom-colors` into `$colors`*, but the [`$custom-colors` with the default color maps](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/0dc44161bcef0aa5eed38680af7b04cea416b6f2/sass/utilities/derived-variables.sass#L103). :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was fixed by changing the imports order:
instead of :

```
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "variables";
```

Do:

```
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "variables";
```